# Why $0!$ is equal to $1$?

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

Many counting formulas involving factorials can make sense for the case $n= 0$ if we define $0!=1 $; e.g., Catalan number and the number of trees with a given number of vetrices. Now here is my question:

> If $A$ is an associative and commutative ring, then we can define an
>   unary operation on the set of all the finite subsets of our ring,
>   denoted by $+ \left(A\right)  $ and $\times \left(A\right)$. While it
>   is intuitive to define $+ \left( \emptyset \right) =0$, why should
>   the product of zero number of elements be $1$? Does the fact that $0! =1$ have anything to do with 1 being the multiplication unity of integers?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25333/why-does-0-1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20969/prove-0-1-from-first-principles

Comment: In your question, where did this come from: "the product of zero number of elements be 1"?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here are two resons.

1. We can define $n!$ to be the number of rearrangements of $n$ distinct objects in a list.  The empty list has one rearrangement: itself.
2. We can define $n!$ as the product of all positive integers $k$ with $1\le k \le n$. If $n$ is zero, we have an empty product.  An empty product must be neutral for multiplication, so it must be 1.

Take your pick.

Comment: Nice attempt! But I think that I have an easier answer: "Because there is only one way to do nothing".

Answer (score 11):

In general, we want the "associative" law to hold in the form:
$$
\times(A \cup B) = (\times A) (\times B)
$$
whenever $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.  What would this mean when $B = \emptyset$ ??

Answer (score 11):

I think that the definition $0!=1$ is the one which makes most of the formulas work nicely.

For example $(n+1)!=n! (n+1)$ also works for $n=0$, as long as $0!=1$.

But most importantly, $\binom{n}{k}$ also works in the case $k=0$. Note that $\binom{n}{0}$ has to be $1$, if you want to have a nice formula for $(a+b)^n$. So for convenienceence, we define $\binom{n}{0}$ to be $1$, and if you want the binomial coefficient to be given by the standard formula, then $0!$ has to be 1.

Answer (score 10):

Multiplying by $1$ is the same as not multiplying by anything at all.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in one of the answers to [this math.SX question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20969/prove-0-1-from-first-principles), you can get the Gamma function as an extension of factorials, and then this falls out from it (though this isn't a very combinatorial answer).

Answer (score 1):

The most elementary way to understand is just to work backwards.  If you start with a sum of several elements and subtract them one at a time, you get $0$ after you finish.  If you start with a product of several elements and divide them out one at a time, you get $1$ after you finish.  Instead of thinking of $0!$ as an empty product and getting all metaphysical, just think of it as nonempty product with all the terms factored out.