# What is Factorial of Zero Cubed?

Tags: factorial

My brother brought something to my attention earlier this morning and I cannot find the answer with just a googling to end the argument, so I have come to you to ask and understand.

$(0! \ 0! \ 0!) = n$

He says that $n$ is $6$. I say that $n$ is $1$.

My reasoning: $0!=1$ so $1*1*1=1$

His reasoning: He won't explain it because he doesn't want to argue about it anymore, but he did mention something about absolute value, which didn't make sense because I saw no $||$ anywhere in the equation.

I don't care who's right. I just want to know what the right answer is and how this equation is solved.

UPDATE:
So, since I spoke to him and showed him what all of you said, he said that the equation was actually $(0!+0!+0!)!=6$, which means that what was written on the piece of paper that he had given me was written in error.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct. $0!$ is $1$, and $1^3 = 1$.

Comment: the only way this is 6 is if $$(0! +0! + 0!)!$$

Comment: Thank you, Chinny84. I will let him know, even though he won't want to hear it.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! There is a [FAQ](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) about how to ask good questions, and the Help Center has other information about participating in the Community, earning Reputation, etc.

Comment: Thanks, hardmath. Was my question not a good question?

Comment: Since "(0! 0! 0!) = n" is a strange way to write the cube of the factorial of zero, maybe actually something else was written, and this is merely an erroneous transcription of it.

Comment: I thought the same thing, GEdgar, but that was what was written on the paper that he handed me.

Comment: @FuzzyMcNubNubs: Perhaps a good Question could be formed somehow from these ingredients, but generally if you can Google the Answer for yourself, I would discourage asking here.  You said you tried, so I'll take your word for it, but entering $0!*0!*0!$ in the Google Search Box does produce the Answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean "what is the factorial of (zero cubed)?", then$$\left(0^3\right)!=0!=1.$$

If you mean "what is (the factorial of zero) cubed?", then $$\left(0!\right)^3=1^3=1.$$

In either case, you're correct.

---

To see why $0!=1,$ see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20969/prove-0-1-from-first-principles).

Comment: I would mean the latter of the two. Thanks, alexqwx.

Comment: Sure. Now go and wipe the smug look off your brother's face!