# Why is $0! = 1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, intuition

I know that we define $n!$ as

$$n! = n\cdot(n-1)!,$$

so that $0! = 1$ follows from $1! = 1$.

However, what I would like to find out is the mathematical intuition behind $0! = 1$, if there is any.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20969/prove-0-1-from-first-principles). Essentially, you want $n!=\frac {(n+1)!}{(n+1)} $. Set n=0 and see what happens.

Comment: @DietrichBurde and that one is a duplicate of  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20969/prove-0-1-from-first-principles

Comment: @EthanBolker Yes, I know. But seeing that a question is already a duplicate of a duplicate makes it perhaps more convincing that the question has been sufficiently discussed on MSE.

Comment: @TimonG. : I think OP already understands that (he stated as much), but wants some intuitive explanation in addition to the technical one.

Comment: What is a more mathematically intuitive explanation than "it follows by plugging in values into the recursive definition of the factorial"?

Comment: Interestingly, the fact that the product of no factors is naturally defined to be $1$ appears to be less obvious than the sum of no term being defined to be $0$. But taking the logarithm explains it easily.

Comment: Empty products.

Comment: $6$ ways to arrange three objects:$$\begin{matrix}(1,2,3)&(1,3,2)\\(2,1,3)&( 2,3,1)\\(3,1,2)&(3,2,1)\end{matrix}$$ $2$ ways to arrange two objects:$$\begin{matrix}(1,2)&(2,1)\end{matrix}$$ $1$ way to arrange one object:$$(1)$$ $1$ way to arrange zero objects:$$()$$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How many ways are there to arrange zero objects in a line? Only one way, the way that arranges no objects.

Comment: :D Well, that was a surprise answer

Comment: I do not think this is correct. The definition of $0!$ has nothing to do with arranging objects.

Comment: It's an interpretation.