# Why is the binomial coefficient $\binom00$ equal to 1?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I can understand why the generalized binomial coefficient $\binom a0$ equals $1$ when $a$ is not zero.

Here $a$ can be any real number.

Why? Well, we have:

$$\binom {a}{n} = \frac{a(a-1)\dots(a-(n-1))}{1.2.3 \dots n}$$

$$\Rightarrow \binom {a}{n+1} = \binom {a}{n} \cdot \frac{(a-n)}{n+1}$$

Now if we plug $n=0$ in the above, that gives us:

$$\binom {a}{1} = \binom {a}{0} \cdot a$$

which is the same as:

$$a = \binom {a}{0} \cdot a$$

So when $a$ is non-zero, we cancel the $a$ term. So we must have
$$\binom {a}{0} = 1$$

That is clear.

But why is $\binom {a}{0}$ also equal to $1$ when $a$ is zero?

At least that is what WolframAlpha says, that it's $1$.

But I find it somewhat counter intuitive. Why is it not zero, for example?

Comment: $0!$ is $1$ - empty product - we like $\binom{x}{0}=1$ regardless of $x$

Comment: That is exactly my question. Why do we want that regardless of x?

Comment: $0!=1$ is also counterintuitive. Although there are no objects, we have $1$ "possibility" to order them. Similar situation here : To choose $0$ objects out of $0$, we have $1$ "possibility". This argument however breaks down in the case of $n<k$, when we have $\binom{n}{k}=0$ per definition.

Comment: See my answer here. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2120973/171839

Comment: The title does not match the main body.

Comment: @Gary Yeah, I noticed. I fixed it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove $0! = 1$ from first principles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20969/prove-0-1-from-first-principles)

Comment: @C.F.G Thanks but... no. My question is about generalized binomial coefficient, not about $0!$

Comment: @peter.petrov: It is. It is $0!/0!0!$ so your question reduces to why $0!=1$.

Answer (score 3):

How many subsets of size $4$ are of a set of size $7$?

$$7\choose{4}.$$

How many subsets of size $0$ (i.e., empty sets) are there in a set of size $0$?

$$0\choose 0$$

which is $1$, because the empty set has exactly $1$ subset of size zero, namely itself.

Comment: This justification also makes sense, I think. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One reason might be from the binomial theorem:
$$(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nka^kb^{n-k},\quad n\in \mathbb N$$
When $n=0$, $$(a+b)^0=1=\sum_{k=0}^0\binom0ka^kb^{0-k}=\binom00a^0b^0=\binom00,\quad a\ne -b$$

Comment: Oh. That's a good point. Makes sense, thanks. Any other justifications?

Comment: such that $a\neq -b$?

Comment: @C.F.G right. edited

Answer (score 0):

You can see it in two ways:

1. $\binom{a}{b}$ corresponds to the number of subsets of a set $E$ with $a$ elements, that have exactly $b$ elements. That means that $\binom{0}{0}$ corresponds to the number of subsets of the empty set, that have no elements. There is one set corresponding to that description, the empty set itself, which means: $\binom{0}{0} = 1$
2. With the formula for the binomial coefficient: We know that $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$, from which we can deduce that $$\binom{0}{0} = \frac{0!}{0!(0-0)!} = \frac{1}{1 \times 1} = 1$$

Knowing that $0! = 1$

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to a combinatorial interpretation, $\binom{n}{k}$ is the number of length-$n$ binary strings with exactly $k$ ones. There is exactly $1$ length-$0$ binary string with exactly $0$ ones.

But it is even possible to extend in a natural way to negative $n$, namely to define $C : ℤ×ℕ→ℤ$ such that:

1. $C(n,0) = 1$ for every $n∈ℤ$.
2. $C(0,k+1) = 0$ for every $k∈ℕ$.
3. $C(n+1,k+1) = C(n,k)+C(n,k+1)$ for every $n∈ℤ$ and $k∈ℕ$.

It can be shown that such a $C$ exists, and this yields the **correct** extension of binomial coefficients that works with the [Newton series](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2319671/21820).

It must be emphasized that you can define *anything* in *any way you like*, but whether or not they have nice properties is another matter. If you want the Newton series to have binomial coefficients as the basis, and the forward-difference operator to be just a shift of the coefficients, then you have *no choice* but to use this definition.