# I have found a Taylor series and a Maclaurin series for a function about x=0.... I have a couple of questions.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, power-series, taylor-expansion

The first part of my question (for my homework) states "Find the Taylor series about $x=0$ of the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$  "...

I have found the taylor series of $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$ to be $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{(1-a)^2}^n{(x-a)^n}}{n!}$$
and the Maclaurin series to be $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)x^n$$

I have a couple of questions...

1. Am I correct in starting my bound as $n=0$? I wasn't sure because some examples have $n=1$. Maybe that's just if the function is undefined for $n=0$?
2. I have found both the taylor series and the maclaurin series as the question asks for the "Taylor series" about $x=0$ which i thought was specifically called a Maclaurin series? But they are different series, so... I am asked to then find the radius and interval of convergence of the answer but I am really confused as to whether I am meant to use the Taylor series version or the Maclaurin series version to do this. Can someone clarify which series out of the ones I found to use for this part?
3. The last half of the question states "Hence or otherwise determine the sum of the series summed from $n=0$ to infinity of $\frac{(n+1)}{2^n}$...
   Does that part have anything to do with either of the series I found for the first half? Or is it just a new part of the question and I should apply the same techniques to find the sum of that series as any other and just ignore the first half of the question to complete this part?

Comment: Learn how to format @ https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Okay the editing is fine now, can anyone please help with my questions? I'm really stuck.

Comment: Your "Taylor series" adds to $$\frac{\exp(x-a)}{(1-a)^2}$$ so cannot be correct. In any case a Taylor series about $0$ **is** a Maclaurin series.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown

How does it add to that?

Comment: I plugged f(x) into the taylor polynomial equation.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{(1-a)^2}+\frac{1}{(1-a)^2}{x-a}+\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{(1-a)^2}{(x-a)^2}}{2!}+\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{(1-a)^2}{(x-a)^3}}{3!}+\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{(1-a)^2}{(x-a)^4}}{4!}+...$$ 

So the general taylor series for this would be $$\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{(1-a)^2}{(x-a)^n}}{n!}$$ wouldnt it?

Comment: When asked to find the value of a specific numerical infinite series, the thing to look for is how it's a special value (at some specific $x$) of your power series.  For example, if a series contains $1/2^n = (1/2)^n$ it might be a power series evaluated at $1/2$.  Concerning the Maclaurin and Taylor terminology, "Maclaurin" just means "Taylor series at 0".  Outside of calculus courses *nobody* who works in math ever uses the phrase "Maclaurin series". We just talk about the power series at 0.

Comment: The factorials in the denominator are wrong, as at $a = 0$ you can see it's not the answer that you already know ($\sum_{n \geq 0} (n+1)x^n$). You should get out a big piece of paper and *carefully* differentiate $1/(1-x)^2$ six times so you see what the pattern really is.  Don't stop after differentiating once or twice.

Comment: The answer i got after differentiating etc is
=$$1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+5x^4+...+(n+1)x^n$$

Comment: I can't edit it now in the comments but ive edited it in the main body but the f(a) is meant to be raised to the nth derivative

Comment: The Taylor series at $0$ *is* the Maclaurin series, which you have found.  All that stuff you're writing with "general" $a$ is irrelevant (and wrong) and should just be deleted.  The power series representation *equals* the function where the power series converges. This stuff all has real numerical meaning.  Look at the *graphs* of $y = 1/(1-x)^2$ together with the graphs of the partial sums of the Taylor series at $0$: $y = 1$, $y = 1 + 2x$, $y = 1 + 2x + 3x^2$, and so on.  Around $x = 0$ they should look quite close to each other.

Comment: Okay, so for my first question in the Maclaurin series, am I correct in staring at n=0 and not at n=1?
You have answered my second question.
For my third question, could you explain how i am meant to use the Maclaurin series to find the sum of the series they provided? I can see how they are similar, but im not too sure how to go about this correctly... I dont have much experience with these yet.

Comment: Regarding “undefined for $n=0$”: it's not, since $0!=1$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20969/prove-0-1-from-first-principles)). And regarding your third question, see the [most frequently asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=frequent) question on this site: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-inftyn1xn).

Answer (score 1):

Your last question: on your second attempt you successfully computed the Maclaurin
series as
$$\frac1{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)x^n.\tag{$*$}$$
You are enjoined to calculate
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n+1}{2^n}.$$
This looks very similar to the RHS of $(*)$. Can you obtain it from the RHS of $(*)$ by making a substitution?

Comment: Do you mean that i substitute something into $$(*)$$ to make it like the other series? x would have to equal 2 and n would have to be -n

Comment: @KaylaMartin Very big hint: $(\frac{1}{a})^n = \frac 1{a^n}$.

Comment: Yeah i can see thats what i need to do but i cant really tell how to do that by substition? What am i allowed to do to it? Can i let $$x^n$$ = $$\frac{1}{2^{n}}$$ ? Thats all  i can think of.

Comment: @KaylaMartin What happens when $x= \frac 12$?