# Yes, $0!=1$, but... by convention?

Tags: soft-question, factorial, products

I have seen many math books, and some of them, very good books, that say that $0!=1$ 'by convention'. I think that $0!$ *must* be $1$ because it is the product of the empty set. That is, for $a\neq 0$,
$$a^0=0!=\prod\emptyset=1$$
What do you think?

EDIT: I'm not asking for a proof that $0!=1$, I really don't be needed to prove that. The question is, *again*, 'what do you think?', that is, do you think that is more convenient to define $0!=1$ by... well, convention, or is it better to see $0!$ as an empty product?

In other words, this is a **soft** question.

Comment: Take a look at [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

Comment: What's your definition of $0!$ ?

Comment: Check this: [Prove $0! = 1$ from first principles](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/20969/42969), or these linked questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/20969

Comment: Since $n!=(n-1)! n$, setting $n=1$ shows a consistent value for $0!$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove $0! = 1$ from first principles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20969/prove-0-1-from-first-principles)

Comment: An empty sum is $0$ and an empty product is $1$, conventionally. Each time, it is the neutral element of the corresponding operation.

Comment: @ajotaxe I address your edit in my answer in the context of power series

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to define $n!$ is  that it’s the number of bijections from a set with $n$ elements to itself ,If the set is empty then the number of elements is $0$ hence $0!=1$ ,since there is only one bijection from the empty set to itself .
 It is also notationally useful for example the power series of $\exp(x)$ is $\sum_{0}^{\infty}x^n/n!$ this makes use of  $0!=1$ .
Another advantage is in combinatorics the number of ways to arrange $n$ objects is $n!$ , so the number of ways to arrange $0$ objects is $1$ ,this makes sense .

Answer (score 2):

I think if you are teaching factorial in a procedural way then trying to.explain the product of an empty set is pretty far outside the context, and simply saying it is a matter of convention is more cognitively in line with where the student is at.

When teaching at the board, I try to separate out *what* a factorial is (number of ways a set can be rearranged) vs *how* to calculate it. Asking the class to tell me how many different ways they can arrange an empty set usually gives them the picture.