# Is this proof true for 0! = 1

Tags: proof-explanation, factorial, fake-proofs

I see proof below for `0! = 1`. Is this true in mathematical scientists' idea?

> (n+1)! = (n+1)n! → (n+1)! ÷ (n+1) = n!

Now if we put 0 to n, we will have:

> 1! ÷ 1 = 0! → 1 = 0!

Is this true in math scientists' opinion?

Comment: Yes it is correct that $0!=1$, and this is the reason

Comment: No, the first line $(n+1)!=(n+1)n!$  is valid only for $n\ge 1$, because $n!$ has no definition for $n=0$, so we cannot write it down for $n=0$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde $(n+1)!=(n+1)n!$ is correct when $n=0$

Comment: No, it isn't. $n!=1\cdot 2\cdot \cdots n$ is not defined for $n=0$. So $0!$ is a **convention**. I cannot be proved from first principles, see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20969/prove-0-1-from-first-principles).

Comment: See [Factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial): "In mathematics, the factorial of a non-negative integer n, denoted by n!, is the product of all positive integers less than or equal to n. The value of 0! is 1, according to the convention for an empty product."

Comment: Unrelated, but I don't agree with  your denomination of ‘mathematical scientist’. I don't think mathematics are really a science.

Comment: "$0!=1$" is true per definition, it need not be proven. To understand why this was defined, the best way is to think of the empty product which has value $1$ allowing many induction proofs starting with $n=0$ instead of $n=1$

Comment: @Bernard In my opinion, who has knowledge in a science in scientist. Not just in experimental sciences. In my opinion math and philosophy are science too.

Comment: @RezaHosseinzadeh: For me, mathematics has to do with poetry.